# How can I run an index.html file on my localhost server?

Tags: apache, web-applications, localhost, webserver

I purchased a fancy little "visual menu maker" over at envato (Code Canyon) from here: https://codecanyon.net/item/z-menu-maker-drop-down-and-mega-menu/9240528

I was using their [sample app where you can test out the tool](https://cc.nkdev.info/ZMenuMaker/) and I was able to create a nice little menu for my site. But you have to purchase a license to export the code.

I purchased the license and [the first "Getting Started" requirement](https://cc.nkdev.info/ZMenuMaker/documentation/) is to "Start your Web Server and open the index.html file. This is where I'm lost. BTW... for reference, you can scroll to [the bottom](https://cc.nkdev.info/ZMenuMaker/documentation/#Save/load) of that documentation page to see all the files that were included in the download.

When I try to open that "index.html" file in my browser, it doesn't load.
I followed some instructions to get my native Mac Apache server running, and everything seems to be working, with my localhost, but I don't know how to open this file through my Apache Web Server.

Any help would be so appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have your Apache installed on your Mac under **/etc/apache2** folder

If you want to serve your html files and related components, you need to tell apache from **where to find your files**

So , you need to configure apache so that it can server your files.

first you need to open an terminal from lunch menu then go to the apache2 installation directory

```
cd /etc/apache2
```

Then you need to open httpd.conf file and make necessary changes,

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

You will see **"DocumentRoot"** line/. Change it with your directory where you put your files.

Change also Directory path with yours. (It should be in same config file such as
with

```
 <Document "some_path">
```

Then you should restart apache server with command

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Now you can try to access your file . you can also check **http://localhost** to validate

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the files somewhere within the DocumentRoot of your Apache web server, and then you should be able to visit them with `http://localhost/` (assuming the index.html file is in the root of the DocumentRoot).

I'm not familiar with the default setting of DocumentRoot on the Mac port of Apache, but you should be able to find that quite easily in the configuration. On Linux that would commonly be found somewhere under /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd.

There may be further configuration needed if the files expect some sort of server-side module to be activated (e.g. PHP), but it sounds like they are just plain HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm not sure how to add these files to the DocumentRoot. I followed this guide to set up my Apache server on Mac: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-13841 . I tried unzipping the folder with all those files in it and putting it in my "/Sites" folder but don't know how to run the index.html file (or if that's even the right place for all the files

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers were given but I think this particular app needed a few extra steps in order to work properly.

The developer got back to me and told me I'd need to install a [MAMP solution](https://www.mamp.info/) in order to run the app.

So I installed that and then took the unzipped folder and all its contents in this folder /MAMP/htdocs/

Then when I visit http://localhost:8888/ZMenuMaker/ the app runs without a hitch!